# Sending blocks of 2D array rows using MPI in C

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I am trying to do a matrix multiplication using MPI in C. (c <= a*b)

I am running the following code on 4 nodes. All the matrices are 8*8 in size.

```
(num of rows in a matrix % num of nodes == 0)
```

matrix b[][] is broadcast so all the nodes get the same copy. For matrix a[][], instead of broadcasting, I want to send only the set of rows that is needed by each node.

But when I run the following code and print the matrix a[][] after MPI_Recv() worker nodes print 0s instead of the values assigned in the master node.

Can you point out what am I doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include "matrix.c" // matrix definitions and matrix operation functions are here

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  MPI_Status status;
  int num, rank, size, tag, high,low,i;
  int offset, tmphigh,rows;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  rows=MAX/size; // MAX is the length(=height) of the matrices
  tag = 201;
  low=rank*rows;
  high=low+rows;


  if (rank == 0) {
    fillMatrix(b,MAX);
    fillMatrix(a,MAX);
  }

  MPI_Bcast(&b[0][0],MAX*MAX,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if(rank==0){
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
      offset=i*rows;
      MPI_Send(&a[offset][0],rows*MAX,MPI_INT,i,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

  }else{
      MPI_Recv(&a[low][0],rows*MAX,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
  }

  printMatrix(a,MAX);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

here is how matrices are created

```
int a[MAX][MAX], b[MAX][MAX], c[MAX][MAX];
int len; //(edited after Jeremy W. Sherman's comment )
//this was the reason that caused this problem. changing this to int len=MAX; solved the problem

void fillMatrix(int (*matrix)[len], int len){
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        for(j=0;j<len;j++){
            matrix[i][j]=j;
        }
    }
    //printMatrix(matrix,len);
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Does the broadcast of b work as expected?  And could you show us how a[][] and b[][] are created?

Comment: yes b works fine. I'm simply assigning few values to all the matrices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might lie `printMatrix()` and `fillMatrix()`. `clang` refused to compile your definition of `fillMatrix()`:

```
so_mpi.c:22:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'len'
void fillMatrix(int (*matrix)[len], int len){
                              ^
```

Dropping `len` from the prototype just creates another problem:

```
so_mpi.c:26:19: error: subscript of pointer to incomplete type 'int []'
            matrix[i][j]=j;
            ~~~~~~^
```

What did work was this:

```
void fillMatrix(int *matrix, int len) {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { 
    int *row = &matrix[i * len];
    for(j = 0; j < len; ++j) { 
      row[j] = j;
    } 
  } 
}

fillMatrix((int *)a, MAX);
fillMatrix((int *)b, MAX);
```

With that change, everything seems to work fine. I used `MAX = 5` and 5 nodes. I prefixed logging statements with the node's rank and added a few more logging statements. Here was the result:

```
$ mpirun -np 5 ./so_mpi
node 1 of 5
node 4 of 5
node 0 of 5
0: filling matrices
0: matrix B:
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
0: matrix A:
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
0: broadcast of B complete
0: sending 1 rows (5 elements) of A to node 1
0: sending 1 rows (5 elements) of A to node 2
0: sending 1 rows (5 elements) of A to node 3
0: sending 1 rows (5 elements) of A to node 4
0: matrix A:
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   1   2   3   4 
1: broadcast of B complete
1: received portion of matrix
1: matrix A:
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
node 2 of 5
2: broadcast of B complete
2: received portion of matrix
2: matrix A:
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
node 3 of 5
3: broadcast of B complete
3: received portion of matrix
3: matrix A:
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   1   2   3   4 
  0   0   0   0   0 
4: broadcast of B complete
4: received portion of matrix
4: matrix A:
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0 
  0   1   2   3   4
```

Comment: I have forgotten to type deceleration of "int len" variable. But your answer led me to finding the solution. And yes error was in len variable. I ll update the question as it was originally. changing "int len;" to "int len=MAX;" solved my problem. But I am not sure about the logic behind it. Could you shed some light on it? Thank you

Comment: `len` serves to specify how many entries are in each row. Your functions declare the `matrix` argument as having type "pointer to array having dimension `len` and type `int`". When `len` is wrong, the size of the type designated by the pointer (the row size) is wrong, so `matrix[i]` retrieves the wrong place in memory.

Comment: does this mean, int (*matrix)[len] will not be treated as a common 2D integer array for any value of len. (So here len is bit like a struct where assigned value to len will decide the type of the struct). Thank you very much for your help